# How to convert string array to SAFEARRAY or VARIANT or COleVariant?

Tags: c++, com, ole, variant, safearray

i'm working about OLE(COM) ,so that i want to convert string array to SAFEARRAY or  CComSafeArray or COleSafeArray or VARIANT or COleVariant.

1. CString[100] -> SAFEARRAY
2. CString[100] -> CComSafeArray
3. CString[100] -> COleSafeArray
4. CString[100] -> VARIANT
5. CString[100] -> COleVariant

converted string array to SAFEARRAY or  CComSafeArray or COleSafeArray or VARIANT or COleVariant is sended OLEMethod to do COM.

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CString strings[100];

CComSafeArray<BSTR> myArray(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  myArray.SetAt(i, strings[i].AllocSysString(), /*copy=*/ false);
}
```